# Show this PHP code in HTML table and row

Tags: php, html, database, html-table, row

I have this PHP code written inside a PHP landing page (HTML inside PHP), and when some visitor access this webpage the code is writing a new file visitors.txt and it shows the IP and time and device of this visitor but it's hard to read when there is many visitors.

I need a way to write this data visitors in row and table where there is table 1 (IP) table 2 (date) table 3 (device) to be more clear to read. Should I put a visitors.html in place or visitors.txt or a visitors.php?

I don't know a lot of HTML and PHP but the idea is (putting some HTML table code and inside this HTML this PHP code that organize data in columns of each new visitors see the page). I need help please.

```
<?php  

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
date_default_timezone_get();
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$useragent = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];   

$msg = "

################BROWSER AND LOCATION DETAILS############
IP : $ip
UA : $useragent
DATE:$date
##################################################
==================================";
$file = fopen("visitors.txt", 'a');
fwrite($file, $msg);

?>
```

Comment: A txt file only contains text, so having tables in them is not gonna be great... maybe consider another file type or storing this information in a database.

Comment: why not just read the Apache access log in PHP, and display the relevant info from that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like:

```
IP             UA               DATE
---------------------------------------------
xxx.xxx.xx.x   aaaaaaaaaa       m/d/Y h:i:s a
xxx.xxx.xx.x   aaaaaaaaaa       m/d/Y h:i:s a
xxx.xxx.xx.x   aaaaaaaaaa       m/d/Y h:i:s a
xxx.xxx.xx.x   aaaaaaaaaa       m/d/Y h:i:s a
```

You must organize how to write :

```
$file = fopen("visitors.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!"); 
$msg = "\r\n".$ip."\t".$useragent."\t".$date;
fwrite($file, $msg); 
fclose($file);
```

start with visitor.txt:

```
################BROWSER AND LOCATION DETAILS############
IP      UA        DATE
```

Comment: yes i type as you say to me , my code now is $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
date_default_timezone_get();
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$useragent = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


$msg = "

################BROWSER AND LOCATION DETAILS############
IP      UA        DATE 
##################################################
==================================";
$file = fopen("visitors.txt", "a"); 
$msg = "\r\n".$ip."\t".$useragent."\t".$date;
fwrite($file, $msg); 
fclose($file);

?>

Answer (score 0):

A better idea would be to store your data as CSV data, so you can load it into almost any spreadsheet, where you can also sort the data.

```
$msg = join( ',', [ $ip, $useragent, $date ])."\n";

fwrite( $file, $msg);
```